# Selenium made a sendKeys for two fields instead of one for some reason

Tags: java, selenium

I made a pretty simple selenium test, where I want to open web page, clear field value, start entering text for this field, select first value from the hint drop down.

Web site is aviasales.com (I just found some site with a lot of controls, this is not an advertisement)

I did

```
DriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.id("flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en")).clear();
```

and it was working perfectly, I also checked via console that this is the only one object on a page like:

```
document.getElementById('flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en')
```

So, in next line I'm sending value:

```
DriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.id("flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en")).sendKeys("LAX");
```

but it send LAX value for both "flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en" and "flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en" for some reason, then i tried

```
DriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.id("//input[@id='flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en'][@placeholder='Destination']")).sendKeys(destinationAirport);
```

but I got the same result:
[image]

What could be a reason and how to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep... there's some weird behavior going on there. The site is copying whatever is entered into the first field into the second for reason I don't understand. I gave up trying to understand it and found a way around it.

Whenever I write code that I know I'm going to reuse, I put them into functions. Here's the script code

```
driver.navigate().to(url);
setOrigin("LAX");
setDestination("DFW");
```

...and since you are likely to use these repeatedly, the support functions.

```
public static void setOrigin(String origin)
{
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en"));
    e.click();
    e.clear();
    e.sendKeys(origin);
    e.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}

public static void setDestination(String dest)
{
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en"));
    e.click();
    e.clear();
    e.sendKeys(dest);
    e.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}
```

You can see the functions but basically I click in the field, clear the text (because usually there's something already in there), send the text, and then press  to move out of the field and choose the default (first choice).

Answer (score 1):

The reason of your issue is the `ORIGIN` and `DESTINATION` inputbox binded keyboard event which used to supply an autocomplete list according to your typed characters.

The binded keyborad event breaks the normal sendKeys() functionality. I met similar case in my projects and questions on StackOverFlow.

I tried input 'GSO' into `DESTINATION` by sendKeys('GSO'), but I get 'GGSSOO' on page after the sendKeys() complete.

To resolve your problem, we can't use sendKeys(), we have to use executeScript() to set the value by javascript in backgroud. But executeScript() won't fire keyborad event so you won't get the autocomplete list. So we need find out a way to fire keyborady event after set value by javascript.

Below code snippet worked on chrome when i tested on aviasales.com:

```
private void inputAirport(WebElement targetEle, String city) {
    String script = "arguments[0].value = arguments[1]";

    // set value by javascript in background
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, targetEle, city + "6");

    // wait 1s
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // press backspace key to delete the last character to fire keyborad event
    targetEle.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);

    // wait 2s to wait autocomplete list pop-up
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // choose the first item of autocomplete list   
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.mewtwo-autocomplete-list > li:nth-child(1)")).click();
}

public void inputOrigin(String city) {
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en"));
    return inputAirport(target, city);
}

public void inputDestination(String city) {
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("flights-origin-prepopflights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en"));
    return inputAirport(target, city);
}
```